# Should I use Telerik Kendo UI Upload or Telerik MVC extensions Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application. In one of views users will select multiple files and attach and upload.   I have license for both.  I used the Kendo Upload to try it out and it works fine. Then I realized that Kendo UI is geared towards mobile application. In my local environment this upload is working fine but should I use the MVC extensions upload since its specifically for web applications?  My intranet application is not used via mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KendoUI has a mobile component, but their regular web stuff is for everything. It can completely be used for regular web applications - nothing prohibits you from that.

The Telerik MVC extensions are not longer developed or supported. KendoUI is their replacement.

Comment: You are right I found this on their website which just verifies at to what you answered above "Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC is the successor of Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC.  It is recommended for new ASP.NET MVC development. The introduction of Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC complements and enhances Telerik’s ability to deliver more value to ASP.NET MVC developers."